# Converting Yeast Recipe to Natural Levain

Tags: baking, yeast, sourdough, conversion

Like many people, I've been doing a good bit of sourdough baking during the quarantine and, like many people, I am in a state of near-constant panic that I have to use up the starter that is constantly growing! I tend to bake breads but am branching out into enriched doughs and desserts. I am curious if there are any hard and fast rules, ratios, or techniques to how to take a yeast recipe (bread, pastry, cake, whatever) and make it with a sourdough levain instead?

Comment: FYI, I am aware of this question, but a) I'm curious if there's any common knowledge that I just don't know, b) it's specifically about pizza and I'm interested in things more broadly: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/103097/switching-yeast-to-sourdough

Comment: Your starter doesn’t have to be constantly growing. You can keep it in the fridge and replenish it when you use some. This is how my sourdough has always worked and I never have to panic about using it.

Comment: @lschoon Sort of? Definitely if the answer is, "it's complicated."

Comment: @Spagirl I keep mine in the fridge too, but our general anxiety levels are probably quite different!